# Arrow types - when to use which

Tags: combat, ranged-attack, rolemaster

Disclaimer: I know this is a "just look into the rule-book" type of question - but I have no rule book at hand and want to come in prepared for my next session. So maybe someone has the rulebook at hand or knows the answer right away.

---

My newish character has a compound bow for his main weapon. I am aware that there are at least three arrow types in rolemaster, but I neither remember all types, nor when to use which best (referring to armor classes & number of enemies).

Comment: Which edition of RM are you using (RM, RM2, RMSS, Classic?) The only arrow type modifiers for RM I've found are in Arms Companion for RM2

Comment: Then let's assume we're running RM2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no variants on "standard" arrows for Rolemaster in either Arms Law or Character Law, arrows are just "Arrows" with a possible bonus for quality/materials that is averaged with the bows bonus to give the overall OB bonus (5.24 p16 Arms Law #1100)

However the Arms Companion (ICE #1120) introduces some variants of arrows that give range and OB modifiers against different Armour Types (AT) p43, 6.17

```
Arrow/AT   20-17  16-13  12-9  8-5  4-1  Range  Damage
Cut        -30    -10    -20   +10  +20  -20%   Standard
Bodkin     +10    +20    +5    +5   +5   +15%   Standard
Flight     -10    -10    -10   -10  -10  +100%  Half
Target     -30    -20    -20   -15  -15  +80%   Half (All crits are Krush)
Wood       -50    -20    -25   -10  +0   +90%   Standard
```

Broadheads are standard RM arrows.

It neglects to mention however what the costs are for these arrows compared to standard arrows. The rules also say that to use one of these special arrows you need to be trained with it or you take a -20 OB penalty; this can be cancelled by developing ranks in each arrow type at half the DP cost for the weapon - which sounds a bit crazy to me really.

There are also rules for heavier arrows and different arrow fletchings, but that's far too much to dump here as well.

Comment: Thanks for the table. Guess I'll have to read up on the topic anyway, since I remembered it slightly wrong.

Comment: I seem to also remember fire arrows and similar.
Does anyone recall where I might have seen that?
It must be RC2, because that's all I've played...

Comment: I understand that, in RM, you have to be trained at wiping your own backside, otherwise you can fall off the toilet seat and suffer an E impact and E embarrassment critical.